# qt - creator: random execution of not the right binary file

Tags: qt, compilation, linker, qt-creator, execution

I want to share a problem that randomly appears with the Qt creator IDE.

Sometimes, when I compile and execute the code, even doing QMake and cleaning the code (even manually), the binary that is being executed, is not the right one.

It seems that an old version is being executed. Usually this problem arises when I have two projects opened (with two qtcreator windows) and one of them calls the binary created by the other.

Have you ever experienced a similar problem? if so, how do you deal with it?

Cheers